# How to get checkbox ids of an inactive view?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

In Android, I built a ListView AA (in Activity A) that is inflated from a String array stored in Resources.  Each item in the ListView opens another ListView BB (in Activity B), which is similarly inflated from another String array in Resources.  Activity B's ListView contains rows of TextView and CheckBox.  Each BB listview will be unique and dependent on listview AA.

I then use each checkbox's state to add to or remove from an ArrayList.  The ArrayList will eventually contain the items selected from ListView BB.

Question is, when I return to ListView AA, I want to be able to get the state of ALL checkboxes, regardless of whether it's corresponding BB listview has been opened or not, and change them according to some condition.  Since each checkbox ID is not unique, how can I find each checkbox's state?

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to loop through the checkboxes per se because if your list scrolls, the checkboxes that are not on the screen do not actually exist.

To correctly preserve the list state, you should use some other mechanism.  Since listview AA is populated from a string array resource, although it sounds crude, you might be best off storing the checked state of the items simply in a private list in your Activity.  In any case, you probably want to have a custom list adapter and override getView().

Hope that helps.